# Python - How to hide labels and keep legends matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, pie-chart

I would like to remove the labels of a pie chart and keep the legends only. Currently, my code has both. Any idea how to remove the labels?

I've tried the code below:

```
plt.legend(labels, loc="best") 

and 

labels=None
```

Bu didn't work.

My full code is:

```
plt.pie(percent,              # data
    explode=explode,    # offset parameters 
    labels=country,      # slice labels
    colors=colors,      # array of colours
    autopct='%1.0f%%',  # print the values inside the wedges - add % to the values 
    shadow=True,        # enable shadow
    startangle=70       # starting angle
    )

plt.axis('equal')
plt.title('Top 5 Countries', y=1.05, fontsize=15) #distance from plot and size
plt.legend( loc="best") 
plt.tight_layout()

countrypie = "%s_country_pie.png" % pname
plt.savefig(countrypie)
```

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you alter your code to the following, it should remove the labels and keep the legend:

```
plt.pie(percent,              # data
    explode=explode,    # offset parameters 
    labels=None,      # OR omit this argument altogether
    colors=colors,      # array of colours
    autopct='%1.0f%%',  # print the values inside the wedges - add % to the values 
    shadow=True,        # enable shadow
    startangle=70       # starting angle
)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.title('Top 5 Countries', y=1.05, fontsize=15) #distance from plot and size
plt.legend( loc="best", labels=country) 
plt.tight_layout()

countrypie = "%s_country_pie.png" % pname
plt.savefig(countrypie)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this should solve it. 
Removing the labels from the pie chart creation and adding the labels to the legend -

```py
plt.pie(percent,              # data
    explode=explode,    # offset parameters 
    colors=colors,      # array of colours
    autopct='%1.0f%%',  # print the values inside the wedges - add % to the values 
    shadow=True,        # enable shadow
    startangle=70       # starting angle
    )

plt.axis('equal')
plt.title('Top 5 Countries', y=1.05, fontsize=15) #distance from plot and size
plt.legend(loc="best", labels=country) 
plt.tight_layout()

countrypie = "%s_country_pie.png" % pname
plt.savefig(countrypie)
```

Comment: Thanks but actually your suggestion labels=country didn't work. Still visible labels and legend.

Comment: Is this working for you (no labels, legend exists) - 
`
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)

plt.legend( loc="best", labels=labels)
plt.show()
`

Comment: I find that I can achieve just a legend and no labels if I either omit the `labels` argument from the call to `plt.pie` or set `labels=None`, and then call `plt.legend(loc="best",labels=country)`. Does this not work for you?

Comment: @TomRon That example puts me legend and labels.. like my code or like adding that labels=country as you suggested.  Angus - it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ok - I'll post as an answer!